# Vanilla JS,Accuweather API, ref error: data not defined. Not sure what my next step should be. Must use location API to call another API

Tags: javascript

```js
//First, get longitude and latitude from our location
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  /*So after page loads, we can grab location*/
  let long;
  let lat;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    /*to find the exact position of the user*/
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      longitude = position.coords.longitude; /*define long variable to use it*/
      latitude = position.coords.latitude; /*define lat variable to use it*/

      /*define api variable to use it and set equal to api key url*/
      const api = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=tKaw1CfZNYzIxjfRsxVph6F=${lat},${long}`;
      /*fetch the api*/
      fetch(api)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json(); /* turn data into json*/
        })
        .then((data) => {
          /*Access the actual data in now returned json*/
        });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best answers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a problem with the request URL, missing `&q=`

your request URL

```
const api = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=tKaw1CfZNYzIxjfRsxVph6F=${lat},${long}`;
```

proper URL

```
const api = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=tKaw1CfZNYzIxjfRsxVph6F&q=${lat},${long}`;
```

And an important note: Make sure that you don't share your private API Key in public

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I removed pieces of it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this code, I've made some changes in fetch function according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Also, could you please test your apiKey in the [Accuweather API](https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-locations-api/apis/get/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search) website

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    /*So after page loads, we can grab location*/
    let lat, long;
  
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      /*to find the exact position of the user*/
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        lat = position.coords.latitude; /*define lat variable to use it*/
        long = position.coords.longitude; /*define long variable to use it*/
        apiKey = ''; //your apiKey
        /*define api variable to use it and set equal to api key url*/
        const api = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=${apiKey}&q=${lat},${long}`;
        /*fetch the api*/
        fetch(api)
          .then(response => response.json()) /* turn data into json*/
          .then((data) => {
            /*Access the actual data in now returned json*/
            console.log(data)
          });
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this and I am still getting the reference error of data is not defined.

Comment: I think that the problem was on the fetch function after made some tests